# .on not working on dynamically generated elements

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table which populates *several* rows with a button element, these rows are generated dynamically using php script:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs data_upload">Upload</button>
```

I simply want to detect a click on this button using jquery -

```
$(".data_upload").on("click", function() {
    alert("asdf");
});
```

Comment: Read the documentation of .on()...

Comment: Your code should run as it is created with php that's not dynamic....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to delegate the event with the nearest static parent, i just used `document` since i dont know the nearest static parent in your context.

Try,

```
$(document).on("click",".data_upload", function() {
    alert("asdf");
});
```